# Building project due arm-none-eabi causes no such instruction error

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm

As first, sorry me please, my English isn't very well...
I am trying to write some project for stm32f746g-disco. I am using arm-none-eabi toolkit. The full source code is at http://github.com/Andrew-Bezzubtsev/stm-glib.git. When I'm trying to build it due:

```
./set_toolchain.sh
cmake ./
make
```

I get the next error: Error: no such instruction:

```
`rbit %eax,%eax'
```

But the fragment of code, where error is happening is:

```
__attribute__((always_inline)) __STATIC_INLINE uint32_t __RBIT(uint32_t value)
{
  uint32_t result;

#if       (__CORTEX_M >= 0x03) || (__CORTEX_SC >= 300)
  __ASM volatile ("rbit %0, %1" : "=r" (result) : "r" (value) );
#else
  int32_t s = 4 /*sizeof(v)*/ * 8 - 1; // extra shift needed at end

  result = value;                      // r will be reversed bits of v; first get LSB of v
  for (value >>= 1; value; value >>= 1)
  {
    result <<= 1;
    result |= value & 1;
    s--;
  }
  result <<= s;                       // shift when v's highest bits are zero
#endif
  return(result);
}
```

Please, help me.

Comment: `eax` is a dead giveaway that you've compiled with your host machine (i.e. x86) compiler. What if you set CROSS_COMPILE in your actual environment instead of running a script which sets it in a subshell then exits (achieving absolutely nothing)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(still can not use comments due to low rep, please convert this to a comment if possible)

eax - is a register from intel (x86) platform, no such register exists on ARM.

You need to figure out why "rbit %0, %1" becomes "rbit %eax, %eax"

upd.:
As @Notlikethat pointed out - you need to setup your cross-compiling environment properly, because currently you are compiling for x86 instead of ARM.